# GitLab pipeline with dotnet and node image

Tags: node.js, .net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm creating a GitLab pipeline which should `build`, `test` and `deploy` a **dotnet core** application with **Angular** application. So far so good!

This project was created using **dotnet cli** with `dotnet new angular`.

For this pipeline I have a default image: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.103`

The problem is that all pipeline jobs need a node installation, because by default when I execute the command `dotnet build` it executes both `node` and `dotnet`. The same applies for `dotnet publish`. This is all configured by default in the `csproj` file.

To solve this issue I added to `before_script` section the following command:

```yaml
before_script:
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
  - apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The pipeline is working, but I wonder if this approach is ok, beucase every job will execute the `apt-get` which causes some performance issues in the pipeline.

Is there a way to make this more reliable? cache for example?

This is how my pipeline looks like:

```yaml
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.103

stages:
  - build
  - tests
  - deploy

variables:
  CSPROJ_PATH: 'TechDay/TechDay.csproj'

before_script:
  - curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
  - apt-get install -y nodejs

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build $CSPROJ_PATH'

tests:
  stage: tests
  script:
    - 'dotnet test $CSPROJ_PATH'

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'dotnet publish $CSPROJ_PATH'
```

Comment: Personally, I would create a custom image with the dotnet/sdk as base image and NodeJS as extra layer. There is no point into installing NodeJS each time that you perform a build.

Comment: @DanielCamposOlivares, can you post an example how to add NodeJS as an extra layer?

Answer (score 0):

I started doing my pipelines the way you did, but have since switched to pulling in a Node image for the NPM build step, and removing that step from my `.csproj` file.  This allows for caching of the Node image and greatly increased my pipeline performance.  You then must define the .Net SDK image in each subsequent job instead of globally.  I have added in an analogous version of my setup in your pipeline file.  I assumed you used the standard `ClientApp` and `wwwroot` structure for client source and distribution locations, respectively.

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - tests
  - deploy

variables:
  CSPROJ_PATH: 'TechDay/TechDay.csproj'
  NPM_ROOT: TechDay/ClientApp
  NPM_DIST: TechDay/wwwroot

build-npm:
  image: node:16
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd $NPM_ROOT
    - npm install
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $NPM_DIST/
    expire_in: 20 minutes  

build:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.103
  stage: build
  script:
    - 'dotnet build $CSPROJ_PATH'

tests:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.103
  stage: tests
  script:
    - 'dotnet test $CSPROJ_PATH'

deploy:
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.103
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'dotnet publish $CSPROJ_PATH'
```